# My code is leaking. How can I solve it?

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-leaks, new-operator, mergesort

My code is leaking. I should delete somewhere the array, what I allocated in this line: 
`T* out_array = new T[size1+size2];`
But I don't know where and how.
Can anyone help me please?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T* merge(T arr1[], int size1, T arr2[], int size2);

template <class T>
T* merge_sort(T arr[], int n)
{
    if(n < 2){return arr;}
    int mid = n/2;
    T *arr1 = merge_sort<T>(arr,mid);
    T *arr2 = merge_sort<T>(arr+mid,n-mid);
    return merge(arr1, mid, arr2, n-mid);
}

template <class T>
T* merge(T arr1[], int size1, T arr2[], int size2)
{
    int i = 0,j = 0;

    T* out_array = new T[size1+size2];

    while((i < size1) && (j < size2))
    {
        if(arr1[i] >= arr2[j])
        {
            out_array[i+j] = arr2[j];
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            out_array[i+j] = arr1[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    while(i < size1)
    {
        //copy the reminder
        out_array[i+j] = arr1[i];
        i++;
    }
    while( j < size2)
    {
        out_array[i+j] = arr2[j];
        j++;
    }

    return out_array;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2, 42, 3, 7, 1};
    int *a2 = merge_sort(a,5);
    for (int i = 0; i<= 4 ; ++i) cout << a2[i] << endl;
    delete[] a2;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: That's what a deconstructor is for.

Comment: It looks like delete[] a2 is taking care of your allocated memory.Because there is no other places where you are allocating the memory. So this delete should be taking care of allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember intervening "in urgence" on an application that was leaking badly:

- the improvements needed to be loaded quickly
- the application was *already* leaking, though less badly
- the non-regressions were known to be incomplete
- the application had never run under valgrind (it's not trivial to run multi-threaded code with tight timeout dependencies under valgrind...)

So, what did I do ? I used `grep` and removed all calls to `new` from the code (*).

- in C++03: `delete` is an error (**) and `new` is a code smell
- in C++11: both `delete` and `new` are an error (**)

And not so surprisingly, all memory leaks disappeared!

Instead of using new, you can use:

- `std::vector` for a dynamically allocated array
- `std::unique_ptr` for a dynamically allocated object
- `std::shared_ptr` in some rare and arcane situations where the actual lifetime of an object obeys complex rules

  (*) or I could have if it had been C++11, in C++03 and in the absence of perfect-forwarding and variadic templates having a `make_auto_ptr` was not really possible.

  (**) in C++03 it could be argued that an expert writing `boost::scoped_ptr` (or equivalent) might need it; in C++11 you can build about every abstraction on top of `unique_ptr` because it's 0-cost.

Answer (score 1):

These are leaking:

```
T *arr1 = merge_sort<T>(arr,mid);
T *arr2 = merge_sort<T>(arr+mid,n-mid);
```

Fix with:

```
template <class T>
T* merge_sort(T arr[], int n)
{
    if(n < 2){return arr;}
    int mid = n/2;
    T *arr1 = merge_sort<T>(arr,mid);
    T *arr2 = merge_sort<T>(arr+mid,n-mid);
    T * res = merge(arr1, mid, arr2, n-mid);
    delete[] arr1;
    delete[] arr2;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to solve the problem of memory leak in your implementation, consider this question: is it really necessary to allocate memory for `out_array` every time you call `merge()`?

I think the answer is no, instead, allocating memory for an auxiliary array (the same size as `arr`) **once** in `merge_sort()` is enough, and pass this array to `merge()`. This method could greatly reduce the times of memory allocation and it's easier to manage the memory allocation.

Comment: The OP should also consider using `std::vector` which already safely handles memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Right, that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate memory like this, you should use `std::unqiue_ptr`. Change

```
T* out_array = new T[size1+size2];
```

to

```
std::unique_ptr<T[]> out_array(new T[size1 + size2]);
```

change the `merge_sort` signature to return `unique_ptr<T[]>`, fix arr1 and arr2 types and do not delete it manually at all. This aproach is better than using `delete[]`, cause an exception can be generated in T's `operator =`. Than, `delete[]` operator will never be called, you will still leak memory, even if you add deletes as in Erik's answer.